# 'Anonymous user' error after passing data with Angular to Rest

Tags: angularjs, django, rest

I am a beginner in Angular and Rest and I have a problem. I have a form in Django template and I want to pass data with Angular, receive it with Rest and process it. Angular knows to pass (post) the data by url to:

```
url(r'^api/nowyPacjent/$', CreateNewPatient.as_view(), name="api_tempPatient"),
```

The CreateNewPatient class looks like this:

```
class CreateNewPatient(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = TempPatient
    queryset = TempPatient.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreateNewPatientSerializer
```

and the serializer looks like this:

```
class CreateNewPatientSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
   surname = serializers.CharField(max_length=70)
   phone = serializers.CharField(max_length=15, required=False)
   age = serializers.IntegerField(max_value=99, min_value=1, required=False)
   company = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, queryset=Company.objects.all()) 
   therapyStart = serializers.DateField(required=False)

   def create(self, validated_data):
       if 'therapyStart' in validated_data:
           therapy_start = validated_data['therapyStart']
       else:
           therapy_start = datetime.date.today()

       if 'age' in validated_data:
           patient_age = validated_data['age']
       else:
           patient_age = 1;

       if 'phone' in validated_data:
           patient_phone = validated_data['phone']
       else:
           patient_phone = ''

    newTempPatient = TempPatient(
        name  = validated_data['name'],
        surname = validated_data['surname'],
        company = validated_data['company'],
        therapyStart = therapy_start,
        age = patient_age,
        phone = patient_phone
    )
    newTempPatient.save()
    newPatient = Patient(
        name=validated_data['name'],
        surname=validated_data['surname'], 
        phone=patient_phone, 
        age=patient_age
        )
    newPatient.save()
    user=None
    request = self.context.get('request')
    if request and hasattr(request,"user"):
        user=request.user
        newTherapyGroup = TherapyGroup.objects.create(
            start = therapy_start,
            patient = newPatient,
            therapist = Therapist.objects.get(user = user),
            company =  validated_data['company']
        )
        newTherapyGroup.save()
    return newTempPatient
```

Everything is fine - after submitting the template form the patient is created - until the code tries to get logged user from the request (just after the last if statement of the serializer). Then I receive the 'AnonymousUser' error and cannot create final model instance. I've tried to pass the data to the Django views and then use the Rest's serializer. However, the error occurred again. I've searched for the answer but nothing was helpful. Please, notice that I don't want to authenticate the logged user but to get data about him.

I think the problem is that Angular somehow loose information about CSRF token and log session and that is the reason of both errors (that is only my assumption).

Below is how Angular config looks like. NewPatientCtrl is responsible for mentioned form and model is one of the form element (and it works fine).

```
angular.module('pacjent', ['ngMessages', 'ui.bootstrap', 'datetime'])
.constant('companyListApi','http://localhost:8000/finanse/api/list/')
.constant('tempPatientApi','http://localhost:8000/pacjent/api/nowyPacjent/')
.factory('ModelUtils', ModelUtils)
.factory('newPatientFormApi',newPatientFormApi )
.factory('companyApi', companyApi)
.factory('mySharedService', mySharedService)
.controller('PacjentCtrl', PacjentCtrl)
.controller('NewPatientCtrl', NewPatientCtrl)
.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ModalInstanceCtrl)
.config(function($interpolateProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
})
```

The interesting thing is that this code works perfect on my colleague's system (Windows 7, Chrome) - the user data is gathered perfectly. However, I've tested it on three different systems (Windows 7 x64, Xubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 14) and several browsers (Firefox, Chromium) on my PCs and the same error occurs.

Thank you a lot for any comments and advice. Sorry also for any non-professional statements.

Answer (score 1):

it is because of this line:

```
user=request.user
# ...
therapist = Therapist.objects.get(user = user),
```

you are trying to get a therapist from your database with an Anynomous user in your ORM - it means a user who is not logged in.

you need `is_authenticated()` in your check:

```
if request and hasattr(request,"user") and request.user.is_authenticated():
    user=request.user
    newTherapyGroup = TherapyGroup.objects.create(
        start = therapy_start,
        patient = newPatient,
        therapist = Therapist.objects.get(user=user),
        company =  validated_data['company']
    )
    newTherapyGroup.save()
```

Comment: Yes, that is true. I've noticed that before. However, the problem is that the user who is logged in is in fact authenticated so it shouldn't be 'Anonymous'. Like I mentioned, my colleague run this code for the same user and it worked. The user received from the request is not 'Anonymous' but is truly the user who is logged in. In my system, I don't know why, the request loose all the data about logged user while passing data with Angular.